# How do I properly format code for desired appending output?

Tags: python-2.x

I'm writing new code and having problem getting desired output. The code reads an html file and finds  tags. it outputs the url only. I insert additional code to complete the  link. I'm trying to insert the url two times within the string.

```
####### Parse for <a> tags and save ############
with open("page1.html", 'r') as htmlb:
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(htmlb, 'lxml')
links = []
for link in soup2.findAll('a', attrs={'href':   re.compile("^https://")}):
    links.append('<a href="'+link.get('href')+'">'"{link}"'</a><br>')

time.sleep(.1)

with  open("page-2.html", 'w') as html:
    html.write('{links}\n'.format(links=links))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desired html output file:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html 

with open("page1.html", 'r') as htmlb:
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(htmlb, 'lxml')



with open("page2.html", 'w') as h:
    for link in soup2.find_all('a'):
       h.write("<a href=\"{}\">{}</a><br>".format(link.get('href'),link.get('href')))
```

Comment: I'm trying to reveal the url. I do not want to  display the hyperlink text. Is this possible? I want to make the url into the hyperlink text.

Comment: As long as you respect the format :  '<a href="{link}">{text}</a>'  it should work

Comment: For some reason that produces blank. Does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me want I want I guess, but not exactly. I would rather see it written out "https://whatever.com/text/text/" than to see "whatever.com/text/text"

```
####### Parse for <a> tags and save ############
with open("page1.html", 'r') as htmlb:
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(htmlb, 'lxml')
links = []
for link in soup2.findAll('a', attrs={'href':   re.compile("^https://")}):
links.append('{0}</a><br>'.format(link,link))

with  open("page-2.html", 'w') as html:
    html.write('{links}\n'.format(links=links))
```